# How can I design data access classes with strategy pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm applying strategy design pattern for data access mechanism.
I have a technology-independent interface;

```
public interface IMyEntityDal
{
    MyEntity Get();
    bool Insert(MyEntity myEntity);
    void Delete();
}
```

And I have 2 concrete data access class that inherit from IMyEntityDal interface.

```
public class SqlMyEntityDal : IMyEntityDal
{
    MyEntity Get()
    {
        //some ef or ado.net code...
    }

    bool Insert(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        //this method is not usable for this concrete class.
    }
    
    void Delete(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        //some ef or ado.net code...
    }
}
```

```
public class OracleMyEntityDal : IMyEntityDal
{
    MyEntity Get()
    {
        //this method is not usable for this concrete class.
    }

    bool Insert(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        //some oracle specific code...
    }

    void Delete(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        //some oracle specific code...
    }
}
```

The client that using IMyEntityDal doesn't know about IMyEntityDal implementation(Sql or Oracle). It injects concrete class with constructor.

```
public class Client
{
    private IMyEntityDal _myEntityDal;
    public Client(IMyEntityDal myEntityDal)
    {
        _myEntityDal = myEntityDal;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        var myEntity = _myEntityDal.Get();
        _myEntityDal.Insert(myEntity);
    }
    
    public void DeleteMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        _myEntity.Delete(myEntity);
}
```

I want to get MyEntity object from SQL and insert to ORACLE database.
I don't want to implement `Insert(MyEntity myEntity)` method for `SqlMyEntityDal` concrete class. And I don't want to implement `Get()` method for `OracleMyEntityDal` concrete class. Also I want to implement `Delete(MyEntity myEntity)` method for either two classes. In this situation, I can choose the concrete class for `Delete()` method with constructor injection. But `Client` is getting and inserting with same database.
How can i design this mechanism?

Comment: Why not use an ORM like Entity Framework which provides a higher level abstraction instead of this data access object? (that's not a strategy).  ORMs are already technology-independent and clients never even know what provider is used underneath. Even ADO.NET works with abstract classes like DbCommand, DbConnection, so you could create technology-agnostic code with it, just by specifying a provider name to a [DbProviderFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory)

Comment: create two interfaces one for each then they will have only the contracts you specify then in client you would inject both having access to both then would simple be _OracleDal.Insert(myEntity) the problem is, if you plan to do this at volume you going to run into majar performance issue doing one record at a time. Also if you intent is to also use ORM then it seems odd.

Comment: easiest is use Ef core, create two dbcontexts, 1 for mssql and one for oracle, inject both repos into manager and do as you like.